# Select all rows where sum(amt) greater than a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table with Invoice and amt as columns

```
+----------+------+
| Invoice  |  Amt | Ledger
+----------+------+
|        1 |    5 |  101
|        1 |    7 |  102
|        1 |   10 |  103
|        1 |    6 |  104
+----------+------+
```

I need to keep excluding the rows until sum(amt) <= value and fetch all the next rows.

Suppose the value is 12

then output rows should be

```
+----------+------+
| Invoice  |  Amt |Ledger
+----------+------+
|        1 |   10 |103
|        1 |    6 |104
+----------+------+
```

Suppose the value is 11

then output rows should be

```
+----------+------+
| Invoice  |  Amt |Ledger
+----------+------+
|        1 |    7 |102
|        1 |   10 |103
|        1 |    6 |104
+----------+------+
```

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Which column defines the order?

Comment: Without an order column you can't do this

Comment: Yes, there is also a ledger column to table. I have edited the post by adding ledger column. this is a primary key as well

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically multi-sets because duplicates are allowed), so I will assume that you have an ordering column.  What you care about is a cumulative sum.  The rest is just filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(amt) over (partition by invoice order by <ordering col>) as cumulative_amt
      from t
     ) t
where cumulative_amt >= 12;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the quick post.